# What happened to the Visual Effects tab, in the Appearance window?

Tags: 11.04, graphics, effects

I just upgraded my Ubuntu 10.10 to the latest 11.04, but I'm not seeing the **Visual Effects** tab in the **Appearance** window. I want to enable/disable extra visual effects like in 10.10. Please help!
[image]

Comment: Would you please post what is your graphic card?

Comment: You have to use Compiz for that, they removed that tab in the Appearance window, sadly :(

Comment: ^ Sorry I can't answer it for you, I would create a detailed walkthrough, with screenshots, but I'm not on my computer right now.

Comment: the visual effects have been removed .

Answer (score 7):

- Install [compizconfig-settings-manager](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]

  `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

  - Warning: [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)
- Launch **CompizConfig Settings
  Manager** by searching from the dash
  in **Unity**, or **Preferences >
  CompizConfig Settings Manager** in
  **Ubuntu Classic**.
- Click on the **Animations** tab.

[image]

- From here, you may adjust all of the
  various window animations to your
  liking

.[image]

Answer (score 0):

try typing    compiz --replace    in the terminal, and also install compiz config settings manager,but be careful with some of the settings like the cube and others,you may have a hard time recovering your desktop if it crashes.

Comment: I guess He is not having problem with compiz, he is not able to find the place from where he can enable extra effects