# Appearance & Effects Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: appearance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to the Visual Effects tab, in the Appearance window?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40213/what-happened-to-the-visual-effects-tab-in-the-appearance-window)

i can't find any effects in the appearance tab.
i want the jelly effect 
HELP ME PLEASE!

Answer (score 1):

The effect you want is called 'wobbly windows'. You enable it in CompizConfig Settings Manager. search for **ccsm** in the Ubuntu Software Center.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not available on 11.04 anymore. For enabling effects install `compizcofig-settings-manager` from Software Centre.

Comment: this is a badly worded answer :/. You need to specify "what" is not available anymore.