# How can I solve the horrible feud between Compiz's wobbly windows and GNOME?

Tags: gnome, compiz, window-management

I've been a fan of Compiz's wobbly windows since I discovered them in 10.04. It's always been one of the first things I enabled. I still have it memorized: Appearance Preferences>Visual Effects>Extra. {I stole the below image from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40213/what-happened-to-the-visual-effects-tab-in-the-appearance-window)}

[image: An image I stole that shows the above Appearance Preferences window.]

But I discovered GNOME 3.2 yesterday. And you can't take me away from it no matter how hard you try. Of course, I wanted my wonderful wobbly windows to work with GNOME... but that turned out to be really hard.

I tried the obvious compiz --replace, but to no avail. It simply kills GNOME and doesn't start anything, leaving my windows stranded, borderless, on the screen, with no way for me to logout or shutdown. I installed all {yes, all} Compiz settings manager-thingies. I changed settings once, twice, and four hundred times.

Of course, Unity tried to grab me by letting me use Compiz's wobbly windows freely and easily. Don't worry, GNOME, I won't leave you!

I've now spent countless hours trying to get the two best things in the universe, GNOME and wobbly windows, to work with each other, but nothing works.

I've done over 25 Bing searches, and I've installed countless bytes' worth of Compiz and GNOME settings managers, but to no avail.

How can I get my new best friend, GNOME 3.2, to work with my old best friend, Wobbly Windows? I'd even be willing to accept a non-Compiz wobbly windows solution, but I don't think anybody makes Wobbly Windows except Compiz.

Comment: Do you have `ccsm`? That is how I manage compiz plugins

Comment: I found someone else that has this problem: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/things-to-tweak-after-installing-ubuntu.html#comment-334404808

Comment: @Matt: If you mean the Compiz Config Settings Manager, then yes.

Comment: Okay, I'm fed up with GNOME. Time to go back to old Ubuntu. However, if anyone finds a solution, be sure to post it here. I may yet go back to GNOME.

Comment: Wobbly windows activated by default on my old PC, now I have 11.10 resizing windows is no longer a joy.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/346361/why-doesnt-wobbly-windows-in-gnome-work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gnome shell uses mutter instead of compiz, and as such, does not use any compiz configurations or extensions. Currently (to my knowledge) there isn't any support in mutter for wobbly windows.

Comment: With my research, I found nearly identical results. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Aww, this is so sad. Are there any future plans to include wobbly windows in Mutter or compiz support in Gnome 3?

Answer (score 1):

Here you are: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3210/compiz-windows-effect/?c=84192
You can see it in action here: https://youtu.be/G8bAVIB9A7A

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged as they might become useless if the link changes in future. It is rather recommended including the main steps in your answer to make it self-sufficient, and include links as a further reading. May I suggest you to edit your answer to include the basic proposed steps ?

Comment: if the link to extensions.gnome.org (also known as the gnome extension portal) will be removed in the future it will be because there will be no more extensions for gnome or because there will be no more gnome

Answer (score 0):

There's a wobbly windows plugin for GNOME Shell now. See https://github.com/magcius/gnome-shell-wobbly-windows

Comment: Could you explain how to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

[Go to the gnome extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/669/wobbly-windows/), install the browser extension as requested, then hit the switch OFF -> ON

if you get tearing, follow instructions at: https://github.com/djreep81/gnome-shell-wobbly-windows/ (I couldn't get it to work in Ubuntu 18.04 w/ Gnome + nVidia)

report any issues to: 
https://github.com/djreep81/gnome-shell-wobbly-windows/issues