# Why doesn't wobbly windows in Gnome work?

Tags: 13.04

I have Ubuntu 13.04 with Gnome 3.8.

I installed `compiz`, `CCSM`. I tried to activate Wobbly Windows, but it doesn't work. It was working properly on Ubuntu 10.10 with Gnome.

Why it isn't working now?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/70890/how-can-i-solve-the-horrible-feud-between-compizs-wobbly-windows-and-gnome

Answer (score 3):

The wobbly windows is a feature not of Gnome, but of the window manager e.g. Compiz.  The Window manager in [Gnome Shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Shell) is Mutter.  and this does does not support Wobbly Windows (yet).  There is a [Gnome Shell extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/669/wobbly-windows/) in beta that allows you to get a wobbly window effect.  This appears to be buggy currently and is only a beta.

Answer (score 1):

*Gnome Shell* support wobbly windows, you can install [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/669/wobbly-windows/) to get wobbly working.

Answer (score 0):

*Gnome shell* does not support wobbly windows.

*Wobbly windows* use the default Ubuntu desktop (Unity). *Gnome shell* doesn't use the *compiz window manager*, so you can't configure it using `ccsm`.

Comment: doesnt support? ? ?

Comment: doesnt suport? ? ?
it was very well works on ubuntu 10.10 with gnome

Comment: @SedSedka Are you using gnome shell? (Looks like this: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-I0g6Tq22gv8/UTN8mrSDhfI/AAAAAAAAOVE/vU79Ekd5_WM/s1600/gnome-3.8-beta-frequent.png) Then yes it doesn't support it. Wobbly windows is a feature of the compiz window manager, which gnome shell 3+ doesn't use.

Comment: On 10.10 you probably used gnome shell 2 (http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d6/Gnome-2-22.png) Which did use compiz.

Comment: If you want wobbly windows in a gnome DE try logging on to a gnome classic session (if this doesn't appear then install gnome-panel)