# How to enable 3D acceleration with Nvidia GT 555m?

Tags: 12.04, unity, nvidia, graphics, effects

I have a Dell XPS 17 (3D) laptop that comes with Nvidia GT 555M. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my laptop (not side-by-side to Windows, but as an application inside Windows using Wubi).

I installed and activated the Nvidia driver (recommended) in Additional Drivers. This went fine and the driver is activated. The problem is,  **I'm unable to use 3D acceleration. 3D desktop effects don't work.**

Please, let me know how to enable 3D desktop effects/3D acceleration.

Comment: Do you have different versions available to install in Additional Drivers? I recall my old laptop's Nvidia card only worked when I installed the most recent driver version from that repository.

Comment: Yep...the additional drivers app showed me two versions of the nvidia driver ! I choose and installed the one,which is "(recommended)" !!

Comment: @Tomas : I installed the latest Nvidia drivers(Beta version) !! Now,the thing is how do I enable 3d desktop effects ????  In older versions of ubuntu,under appearances we can tick or untick the 3d effects,ryt ?
how do i do it in ubuntu 12.04 ???? pls let me know.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments and some Google I think by the 3D acceleration you mean the fancy effects that the old Ubuntu versions used to have, e.g. windows zooming out when you minimise but also the more complicated stuff, such as wobbly windows.
I think this is something else than the actual 3D acceleration, which you have already enabled by installing and activating the proprietary drivers.

In order to do these simple effects, please see the top rated answer in [What happened to the Visual Effects tab, in the Appearance window?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40213/what-happened-to-the-visual-effects-tab-in-the-appearance-window) Briefly put, you can use CompizConfig Settings Manager (CCSM) to enable the "3D" effects. The selection in Appearance has been removed, but you can still edit these things manually.

The fancy animations (wobbly windows, etc) are also in CCSM. Just be careful with changing these settings and playing around, if you change the wrong settings you *will* break Compiz and have to reset to the defaults, as explained in [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

If I misunderstood please post it here.